# Programmatically get application usage time from Screen Time in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Is there any way to get the application usage time from Screen Time API? If so how can we get it in Swift language?

Comment: No. There is no api for this. It is private information.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the actual use time of a given application is not possible using current APIs in Swift. The closest we have is DeviceActivity. See the WWDC video here https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10123/ as well as the apple docs here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/deviceactivity/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Is there any examples, to know more about the DeviceActivity API?

Comment: The documentation linked includes examples. Note that none of them will give your app the data directly (that's on purpose). But you can display reports. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/deviceactivity/deviceactivityreport